# linux command line: cut (with empty fields)

Tags: linux, command-line, cut

I have a file (input.txt) with columns of data separated by spaces. I want to get the 9th column of data and onwards.

Normally I would do:

```
cut -d " " -f 9- input.txt
```

However, in this file, sometimes the fields are separated by multiple spaces (and the number of spaces varies for each row / column). cut doesn't seem to treat consecutive spaces as one delimiter.

What should I do instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
sed -r 's/ +/ /g' input.txt|cut -d " " -f 9-
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `sed` to replace `n` whitespaces with a single whitespace:

```
sed -r 's/\ +/\ /g' input.txt | cut -d ' ' -f 9-
```

Just be sure there aren't any tabs between your columns.